# How to move HTML element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, element, move

How to move HTML element to another element. Note that, I don't mean moving element's position. Consider this HTML code:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<span id="to_be_moved"></span>
```

I want to move "to_be_moved" to "target" so "target" has child "to_be_moved" now. So the result should be like this:

```
<div id="target"><span id="to_be_moved"></span></div>
```

I've searched in google (especially using prototype framework) but all I've got is moving position, not as I want. Thanks before.

Answer (score 39):

```
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(  document.getElementById('to_be_moved') )
```

Comment: What about "to_be_moved"? Is it still in its original place?

Comment: Huh? The element's parent will change, so it's "moved". The node isn't "removed" though because it's now elsewhere in the DOM tree.

Comment: "If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() **moves** it from its current position to the new position..." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild.  Useful to know that the combination amounts to a move, and not a copy.   It is not implicit in the naming.  node.cloneNode() will...do what it says.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with native DOM elements, the Javascript method [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/appendchild) will suit your needs.

In native Javascript, `document.getElementByID` is probably your best bet in getting the DOM element, so...

```
var target = document.getElementById('target')
document.getElementById('to_be_moved').appendChild(target)
```