# Proper way to select multiple options from <select> form field using CasperJS/PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs

I am automating testing of a web page in which there exists two multi select fields on a form.  The one on the left contains a list of country names, the one on the right contains the ones you have selected.  Countries can exist on one list but not the other.  When you click a country it moves to the other list (you get the idea).  When the form is submitted the values in the POST look like this (from chrome inspection):

```
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes]:
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AF
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AX
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AL
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:DZ
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AS
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AD
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AO
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AI
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AG
data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]:AR
... (ALL countries not selected are in this list)

data[Campaign][country_codes]:
data[Campaign][country_codes][]:US
data[Campaign][country_codes][]:AQ
data[Campaign][country_codes][]:BD
... (this part contains the ones we have selected)
```

and here is what the HTML looks like for the select list of the countries you want included:

```
<select name="data[Campaign][country_codes][]" multiple="multiple" id="CampaignCountryCodes" data-quicklist-ref="CampaignCountryCodes_quick" data-alter-ref="CampaignCountryCodes_alter">
<option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option>
<option value="AQ" selected="selected">Antarctica</option>
<option value="BD" selected="selected">Bangladesh</option>
</select>
```

What I don't understand is, how would I set those form values at the time of testing?  I don't really understand the `<select>` attribute of a form comes through as an array of values or what?  I would like to be able to submit the form and have a list of countries that are on, and a list that are off.

Here is an example of what I do to set other values on the form that works correctly.  I really have no idea how to do this for a multiple and that is the question being asked.

This example is a text area that works just great.

```
casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="some text area"]'),
   function success() {
        test.assertExists(x('//*[@id="some text area"]'));

        this.fill('form#campaign_form', { 
            'data[Campaign][some_field]': 'include',
            'data[Campaign][the_field]': myvar + "\n"
        }, true); 
   },
   function fail() { ... }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Are you asking how to set multiple options in CasperJS (answerable) or are you asking how to decide which to ones to click at testing time (unanswerable)? Can you show what you already tried?

Comment: Does that work for you: [CasperJS/ Javascript Selecting Multiple Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986521/casperjs-javascript-selecting-multiple-options)?

Comment: The answer you have referenced only selects the values in a list.  I need to remove an option from one side and add it to the other.

I will update the question with an example of what I do with casper for other form values (not multiple)

Comment: I though that's what the page is doing for you. Why would *you* need to do that? So you actually want to move the `<option>` from one select box to another?

Comment: Yes I want to actually move the value from one list to the other.  For example, I only want "US" to show up on the active side (right) and all over values are off (left side).  Or turn on CA and US for Canada and US.

Answer (score 2):

You can [move the options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357575/how-to-move-html-element) from one select to the other:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    var values = ["US", "CA"];
    var src = document.querySelector('[name="data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]"]');
    var dest = document.querySelector('[name="data[Campaign][country_codes][]"]');
    values.forEach(function(val){
        dest.appendChild(src.querySelector('[value="'+ val +'"]'));
    });
});
```

After that you probably still have to select them. Just because the options are present in the select box doesn't mean that they are sent to the server when you submit the form they are in. You need to select the values:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    var values = ["US", "CA"];
    var src = document.querySelector('[name="data[Campaign][unselected_country_codes][]"]');
    var dest = document.querySelector('[name="data[Campaign][country_codes][]"]');
    values.forEach(function(val){
        dest.appendChild(src.querySelector('[value="'+ val +'"]'));
    });

    // select intended values
    [].forEach.call(dest.options, function(opt){
        if (values.indexOf(opt.value) !== -1) {
            opt.selected = true;
        }
    });

    // trigger change event to run some page JavaScript
    var evt = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
    evt.initUIEvent("change", true, true);
    dest.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

---

I suspect all of this is not necessary, because you should be able to select the necessary options as seen in [CasperJS/ Javascript Selecting Multiple Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986521/casperjs-javascript-selecting-multiple-options) and they should appear in the target select box.